# Can a python callback call a .NET method?

Tags: c#, python, mono, pygtk, gtk#

I've got a BeagleBone Black running Debian, with a 480x272-pixel cape (touch screen) attached. I'm using [wicd](https://launchpad.net/wicd) for the wired/wireless interface, because it has a very nice [python/gtk-based solution](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) already ready for end users to easily set up various network configurations.

The problem is that the end users will not have access to a physical keyboard, so in order to enter wifi settings, they will need a virtual keyboard.

My main project is mono-based (C#), and I've got a virtual keyboard written in [GtkSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) (C#). I can call it from my other C# project files fine, but can't open it from this python module.

I usually call the `wicd` client with:

```cs
    private void CallWicdDialaog()
    {
        Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/usr/bin/wicd-client",
                Arguments = "-n",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
    }
```

This starts the python process in the native Debian OS, not through the mono/C# project. I need no "communication" between `wicd` and my mono project anywhere else than this virtual keyboard.

The `wicd` project hooks a gtk *focus* event within its `guiutil.py` file like this:

```py
class LabelEntry(gtk.HBox):
    """ A label on the left with a textbox on the right, 370 pixels wide. """
    def __init__(self,text):
        ...
        self.entry.connect('focus-in-event', self.show_characters)

    ...

    def show_characters(self, widget=None, event=None):
        # When the box has focus, show the characters
        """ I would like to hook my virtual keyboard in here """
        if self.auto_hide_text and widget:
            self.entry.set_visibility(True)
```

What I would like to do, is to call my virtual keyboard within the `show_characters` definition.

How would I do this?

- Is there a way to communicate from this python callback to mono?
- Is there a way to inject a callback into python FROM mono?
- Do I need to rewrite my GtkSharp-based keyboard in python, and let the Debian OS handle everything natively?
- Is there another virtual keyboard out there that could handle such a small screen space?
- Is there a different solution I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. These system integration problems are never easy to solve. Here are some things I would look at.

When it comes to launching the keyboard. Figure out how to do it with a line in the terminal. Once you have that you can figure out control flow.

Transmitting the data could be interesting. First two things that come to mind are:

1. Try setting up the C# keyboard to return text you can parse via stdout/in. Then simply fork() to the keyboard from the python app. It works for bash, why not this?
2. Write a tiny udp server in the C# project, and have it send the output to the python app. Do it all on the internal loopback and you shouldn't be advertising open ports.
3. Run both at start up, and have both listen to system interrupts for the control switching.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could port your python code to [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) this should allow calls in both directions but you may have to build IronPython for your target environment.

If you can provide a C/C++ interface to your keyboard you can use it as an extension module, this may be less effort than porting it to Python directly.

Alternatively you could call your keyboard as an external process and use pipes from within subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a standalone GtkSharp application using your keyboard, print to stdout and run it from python with [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).